# How to suppress Spinner double clickable problem of Android

Tags: java, android, spinner

How to suppress Spinner double clickable problem of Android.

Try launch any application that having Spinner.

Then double tap it.

It will show context menu twice.

Answer (score 1):

It does not do this on the DROID or the Nexus One. I can only get it to occur in the emulator, and rarely at that. I would not worry about the problem.